# React-router cannot get component when manually modifying url or page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I used `HasRouter` in my app and this worked fine but I got tiered of seing the "#" in the url.

In order to remove it I found that I should use the `BrowserRouter` together with `browserHistory`.

I am obviosly doing something wrong since I can not get this to work, my code:

```
import {
  Route,
  browserHistory,
  BrowserRouter,

} from "react-router-dom";

      <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Intro} />

          {routes.map(prop =>
             (
               <Route
                 path={prop.path}
                 component={prop.component}
                 key={prop.id}
               />
            ))}

        </div>
      </BrowserRouter >,
```

package.json:

```
   "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
```

**Scenario**: 
I arrive at my intro page and press a button to come to a "Room" component. 
The url looks like "http://localhost:8080/Room".

When pressing the button from the intro page I get no errors BUT
If i were to type in this "http://localhost:8080/Room" manually in the url

I get:

> Cannot GET /Room

What am I doing wrong?